# What was the data they needed from the black hole?

Tags: interstellar

Supposedly in order to complete the theory of everything needed to master gravity, the physicists needed some data that could only be obtained from a black hole. What was it that they needed?

Comment: I figured it had to be the vector/gradient map of gravity once inside the event horizon? By getting the gravity of each point inside the black hole, one could reverse engineer it to determine the correct gravity equations in a black hole. From there, perhaps reconcile gravity with quantum mechanics. And from there, perhaps learn to manipulate gravity with quantum/small devises. Having said all that, I have no idea how it was able to transmit that information, along with the right mapping information through the event horizon. Nor do I understand how Cooper left the black hole once inside...

Comment: Yeah, it does seem that they've skipped over that question. I don't think they're even witnessing the true gravity of a black hole, otherwise they'd be crushed. In fact, there doesn't seem to be any gravity in the tesseract.

Comment: “Nor do I understand how Cooper left the black hole once inside” — I think he was brought out by the future humans, who have worked out how to manipulate gravity, and can thus have some control over black holes. Of course, they only figured this gravity stuff out thanks to the work started by Cooper’s daughter and completed using the data he sent back to her from the black hole via the watch, but if you’ve seen any recent Doctor Who you should be comfortable with that sort of stable time loop.

Comment: We don't know for certain it was future humans- that was just supposition by Coop.

Comment: @Keen, this isn't the duplicate, it was written first.

Comment: @PointlessSpike: but the other question has an answer, and this one doesn't.

Comment: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." It doesn't fulfill both of those criteria, only one of them.

Comment: @PointlessSpike The other question is more fleshed out, so I made it the master question.

Comment: Re: which one was closed, see: [Should we always close the newer question as the duplicate?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate)